# Apply conditional formatting if other cell is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

2 Columns.

```
C2 | D2  
C3 | D3  
C4 | D4  
C5 | D5
```

I want it to apply conditional formatting to D2 if C2 has information in it, and D2 is blank. (will be a date). If C2 is empty, then D2 should have no formatting. I don't want D2 to be formatted if C2 has text, and D2 has text.

Picture: I would want it to look like this:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290) formula should serve your purpose well.

Create a new rule in the conditional formatting menu. Set the range of your rule to `D2:D` so that the formatting is applied to column D. Then, in the Condition dropdown menu, select "Custom formula is." In the input field, enter `=NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C))`. (The `=` implies the rest is a formula. The `NOT` formula negates the value returned by its argument. Since you want the formatting rule to apply if the corresponding cell in column C is NOT empty, you will need to use this.) Finally, set the formatting to suit your needs.

Comment: Worked very well. I ended up using " =AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C)),(ISBLANK(D2:D))) ". Because I didn't want the D column to be formatted if it had text.(Forgot to include that in my message). Thank you very much :)

Comment: Critical to have the = in front of the conditional statement.  So `=NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C))` works, but `NOT(ISBLANK(C2:C))` will not.  Hopefully saves some people some time!  Google Sheets is so powerful but definitely has some documentation concerns especially for folks coming from Excel.

Comment: UPDATE - Now conditional formatting has a "Cell is empty" condition as a provided option.

Comment: But remember, sometimes a cell isn't quite empty, and isn't quite blank, but still might be =="" so C2:C=="" might be a good check when the others don't seem to work.

Comment: **Sometimes a cell isn't quite empty**, so if `NOT(ISBLANK(A2))` is not working, highlight the offending cell (which *looks* empty but is seemingly erroneously highlighted) and press **delete (or backspace)**. That just worked for me. I found this question & answer because I was driving myself crazy thinking the formula is logically correct and that I did not *see* anything inside this cell (`A2`), yet it was highlighted. As soon as I "deleted" the supposed contents, the cell ceased being highlighted.

Comment: I could not get the =NOT(ISBLANK(C2)) to work in conditional formatting (it works fine in a cell). 
It automatically assumes a relitive reference so I had to amend it to =NOT(ISBLANK($C2)) to fix the column it was checking.